# How to activate a workbook that has dates in file name and change weekly?

Tags: excel, vba

I need your help.
I have this main macro that opens a previous day file by using a cell reference (location of the file and file name). The opened file is used to copy the data from its worksheets (4 worksheets)to the main macro. I recorded the macro and the date was hard coded. When i will run the macro for next week, it will give me an error since the previous file name was hardcoded. I tried using activeworkbook but it wont work since i go back and fort between the main file and preivous file when copy pasting.

sample query below

```
Sub OpenPrev()
'
' OpenPrev Macro
'

'
    ChDir "\\hfx1nas02\hfx1_data02_sh$\Share2\HFX MDBG\Marlon\MarkitEDM\EDM_WORK"
    Workbooks.Open Range("M1").Value & ".xlsx"
    Sheets("BBG COMDTY - Cur Data").Select
    Range("A3:AF10000").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("EDM Summary Macro 1.1.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("BBG COMDTY - Prev Data").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Windows("EDM_Matcher_Inbox_20191202.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("BBG PK BBGID - Cur Data").Select
    Range("A3:AJ10000").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("EDM Summary Macro 1.1.xlsm").Activate
    ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=1
    Sheets("BBG PK BBGID - Prev Data").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    ActiveWorkbook.Activate
    Windows("EDM_Matcher_Inbox_20191202.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("BBG BO - Cur Data").Select
    Range("A3:AH10000").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("EDM Summary Macro 1.1.xlsm").Activate
    ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=2
    Sheets("BBG BO - Prev Data").Select
```

Comment: See [How to Avoid Using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) first.

Comment: As far as your main issue, `Dim wb as Workbook`, then `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Range("M1").Value & ".xlsx")`. Now you have a reference to the opened workbook and you don't have to refer to it by name.

Comment: Rule #1: never use macro recorder code as-is. You hardly ever **need** to `Select` or `Activate` anything to do 99.99999% of everything you could ever want to do in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Workbooks.Open Range("M1").Value & ".xlsx"
> ```

`Workbooks.Open` is a *function* - it *returns a value* - in this case, a reference to the `Workbook` object that was opened, if the function return successfully without raising any errors.

You are discarding that object reference. Use it!

```
Dim book As Workbook
Set book = Workbooks.Open(ActiveSheet.Range("M1").Value & ".xlsx")
```

This instruction assumes opening the workbook made it the `ActiveWorkbook`:

> ```
> Sheets("BBG COMDTY - Cur Data").Select
> ```

Don't work off side-effects and assumptions.

```
Dim currentCOMDTYSheet As Worksheet
Set currentCOMDTYSheet = book.Worksheets("BBG COMDTY - Cur Data")
```

You don't need to `Select` a `Range` to `Copy` it. You only need to `Select` a `Range` when you want to work off the `Selection`, *and you almost never want to do that*.

> ```
> Range("A3:AF10000").Select
> Selection.Copy
> ```

Instead, just work off the `Worksheet` object you've got:

```
currentCOMDTYSheet.Range("A3:AF10000").Copy
```

But let's hold off a second, and see where that's being copied to first:

> ```
> Windows("EDM Summary Macro 1.1.xlsm").Activate
> Sheets("BBG COMDTY - Prev Data").Select
> Range("A3").Select
> Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
>     :=False, Transpose:=False
> ```

(side note: line continuations `_` should generally be avoided, but when you do use them, avoid splitting a named argument in the middle - `SkipBlanks:=False` should be on a single line)

I'm assuming the "EDM Summary Macro 1.1.xlsm" workbook is the workbook that's hosting your VBA project. If that's the case, then you don't need to dereference its `Window` off the `Windows` collection, nor to dereference it off some `Workbooks` collection (which would be a much more straightforward way to activate that workbook than getting its `Window`). The workbook that's hosting your VBA project is always in scope, and it's always called `ThisWorkbook` (unless you renamed it, but don't do that).

And since all worksheets in `ThisWorkbook` that exist at compile-time each have a *code name*, you don't need to dereference the worksheet *at all* - it's right there, readily usable. Maybe it's called `Sheet3` or `Sheet21` though: find the "BBG COMDTY - Prev Data" sheet in the VBE's *Project Explorer*, then set its `(Name)` property to a valid VBA identifier, e.g. `PrevCOMDTYDataSheet`. And now we can paste directly there:

```
currentCMDTYSheet.Range("A3:AF10000").Copy PrevCOMDTYDataSheet.Range("A3")
```

But that would bring in formats and borders and validations and formulas, and we only want the values. In that case, we don't need to even get the clipboard involved:

```
PrevCOMDTYDataSheet.Range("A3:AF10000").Value = currentDataSheet.Range("A3:AF10000").Value
```

And done!

Similar here:

> ```
> Windows("EDM_Matcher_Inbox_20191202.xlsx").Activate
> Sheets("BBG PK BBGID - Cur Data").Select
> Range("A3:AJ10000").Select
> Application.CutCopyMode = False
> Selection.Copy
> Windows("EDM Summary Macro 1.1.xlsm").Activate
> ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=1
> ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=1
> Sheets("BBG PK BBGID - Prev Data").Select
> Range("A3").Select
> Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
>     :=False, Transpose:=False
> ```

You already have the `book` reference, so no need to activate the window again; the BBGID data sheet needs an object reference:

```
Dim currentBBGIDSheet As Worksheet
currentBBGIDSheet = book.Worksheets("BBG PK BBGID - Cur Data")
```

And then similar as above:

```
PrevBBGIDSheet.Range("A3:AJ10000").Value = currentBBGIDSheet.Range("A3:AJ10000").Value
```

Same with the last block:

> ```
> ActiveWorkbook.Activate
> Windows("EDM_Matcher_Inbox_20191202.xlsx").Activate
> Sheets("BBG BO - Cur Data").Select
> Range("A3:AH10000").Select
> Application.CutCopyMode = False
> Selection.Copy
> Windows("EDM Summary Macro 1.1.xlsm").Activate
> ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=2
> Sheets("BBG BO - Prev Data").Select
> ```

```
Dim currentBBGBOSheet As Worksheet
Set currentBBGBOSheet = book.Worksheets("BBG BO - Cur Data")

PrevBBGBOSheet.Range("A3:AH10000").Value = currentBBGBOSheet.Range("A3:AH10000").Value
```

So, recap: first step is to **name your sheets** in `ThisWorkbook`. You want `PrevCOMDTYSheet`, `PrevBBGIDSheet`, and `PrevBBGBOSheet` worksheets named in the VBA project, and then this can be a first-pass cleanup:

```
Public Sub OpenPrev()

    Dim book As Workbook
    Set book = Workbooks.Open(ActiveSheet.Range("M1").Value & ".xlsx")

    Dim currentCOMDTYSheet As Worksheet
    Set currentCOMDTYSheet = book.Worksheets("BBG COMDTY - Cur Data")
    PrevCOMDTYSheet.Range("A3:AF10000").Value = currentCOMDTYSheet.Range("A3:AF10000").Value

    Dim currentBBGIDSheet As Worksheet
    currentBBGIDSheet = book.Worksheets("BBG PK BBGID - Cur Data")
    PrevBBGIDSheet.Range("A3:AJ10000").Value = currentBBGIDSheet.Range("A3:AJ10000").Value

    Dim currentBBGBOSheet As Worksheet
    Set currentBBGBOSheet = book.Worksheets("BBG BO - Cur Data")

    PrevBBGBOSheet.Range("A3:AH10000").Value = currentBBGBOSheet.Range("A3:AH10000").Value

End Sub
```

Second-pass, I'd remove the hard-coded 10000 row numbers, and actually work out what *actual size* `Range` needs to be copied over.

Comment: wow thank you so much Mathieu! It is working now and i have learned a lot from this! for the rage like Range("A3:AJ10000") I put 10000 coz the output data i am copying varies daily, how can set a range whereby it will just copy all the data in that range